# Spring Cloud Stream starter application for a generic Message Channel source

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

There is a "rabbit" source application that listens to specified rabbit queues and generates messages, but I could not find a "message channel" source which can be bound any message broker that provides a binder (Rabbit, Kafka, others). Such a source could have "channel name" and "consumer group name" as parameters, which will dynamically bind to the specified channel and emits received messages to the bound output channel.

I can create such a custom source application, but since this looks to me like a common need, I am wondering why there isn't one already and whether I am misunderstanding something basic about "sources"?

**EDIT:**
I am thinking a Source that will listen to a Message Channel whose name is specified as a property and then emits received messages to the bound output channel. Kind of opposite to what the 'router' sink does where the output channel can be specified dynamically, here I want to specify input channel dynamically.

The need for this came up when one my processor applications was producing messages to multiple output channels, similar to the 'router' sink. I need other streams to process messages in those channels.

Say processor1 sends messages to an auxiliary-channel, in addition to the main output channel. I am thinking of creating streams like the following:

```
source | processor1 --auxChannel=auxiliary-channel | normal-output-processor | normal-output-sink

channel --channelName auxiliary-channel --groupName mygroup | auxiliary-output-processor | auxiliary-output-sink
```

(Here "channel" is the proposed Channel source)

Does this make sense or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Please, share more info about your Source specifics. If there is no one, we always are opened for contribution. So, your generic source may make it into our standard app starters catalog.

Comment: Artem, I edited the question to add more details. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find the sample and docs in the Internet, but I heard there is a `fan in/fan out` support in the Spring Cloud Data flow with named channels: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#arch-streams

Comment: Artem, Thank you! Named channel is exactly what I needed. There is no need for the source app. I just have to use a named channel. That is, the second stream in my example would be-   :auxiliary-channel > auxiliary-output-processor | auxiliary-output-sink

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Artem's comment, I figured out what to do. There is no need for the source app. We just have to use a named channel, like:

```
source | processor1 --auxChannel=auxiliary-channel | normal-output-processor | normal-output-sink
:auxiliary-channel > auxiliary-output-processor | auxiliary-output-sink
```